# Vercel Postgres prepared statement does not exist when seeding database

Tags: javascript, postgresql, vercel, pgbouncer

I have been following [this](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/setting-up-your-database) learning path from Vercel for Next.js 14. In the linked section, a Postgres database is created (on Vercel) and seeded using the given seed.js and placeholder-data.js scripts. (see below)

However, when I run the seeding script using `node -r dotenv/config ./scripts/seed.js`, I receive an error:

```
> node -r dotenv/config ./scripts/seed.js

Created "users" table
Seeded 1 users
Created "customers" table
Seeded 10 customers
Created "invoices" table
Error seeding invoices: NeonDbError: db error: ERROR: prepared statement "s142409" does not exist

Caused by:
    ERROR: prepared statement "s142409" does not exist
    at execute (/Users/ecki/Documents/Dev/Web/yourgix-v2/node_modules/@neondatabase/serverless/index.js:1539:48)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async seedInvoices (/Users/ecki/Documents/Dev/Web/yourgix-v2/scripts/seed.js:67:30)
    at async /Users/ecki/Documents/Dev/Web/yourgix-v2/scripts/seed.js:166:3 {
  code: '26000',
  sourceError: undefined
}
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

NeonDbError: db error: ERROR: prepared statement "s142409" does not exist

Caused by:
    ERROR: prepared statement "s142409" does not exist
    at execute (/Users/ecki/Documents/Dev/Web/yourgix-v2/node_modules/@neondatabase/serverless/index.js:1539:48)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async seedInvoices (/Users/ecki/Documents/Dev/Web/yourgix-v2/scripts/seed.js:67:30)
    at async /Users/ecki/Documents/Dev/Web/yourgix-v2/scripts/seed.js:166:3 {
  code: '26000',
  sourceError: undefined
}
```

If I check the database entries afterwards, I see that some entries in the invoices table were created (like 8 out of 10).

The .env holds values for these variables:

```
POSTGRES_URL
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING
POSTGRES_USER
POSTGRES_HOST
POSTGRES_PASSWORD
POSTGRES_DATABASE
```

seed.js

```
const { sql } = require("@vercel/postgres");
const {
  invoices,
  customers,
  revenue,
  users,
} = require("../app/lib/placeholder-data.js");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

async function seedUsers() {
  try {
    await sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`;
    // Create the "invoices" table if it doesn't exist
    const createTable = await sql`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password TEXT NOT NULL
      );
    `;

    console.log(`Created "users" table`);

    // Insert data into the "users" table
    const insertedUsers = await Promise.all(
      users.map(async (user) => {
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
        return sql`
        INSERT INTO users (id, name, email, password)
        VALUES (${user.id}, ${user.name}, ${user.email}, ${hashedPassword})
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
      `;
      })
    );

    console.log(`Seeded ${insertedUsers.length} users`);

    return {
      createTable,
      users: insertedUsers,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error seeding users:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function seedInvoices() {
  try {
    await sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`;

    // Create the "invoices" table if it doesn't exist
    const createTable = await sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS invoices (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id UUID NOT NULL,
    amount INT NOT NULL,
    status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL
  );
`;

    console.log(`Created "invoices" table`);

    // Insert data into the "invoices" table
    const insertedInvoices = await Promise.all(
      invoices.map(
        (invoice) => sql`
        INSERT INTO invoices (customer_id, amount, status, date)
        VALUES (${invoice.customer_id}, ${invoice.amount}, ${invoice.status}, ${invoice.date})
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
      `
      )
    );

    console.log(`Seeded ${insertedInvoices.length} invoices`);

    return {
      createTable,
      invoices: insertedInvoices,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error seeding invoices:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function seedCustomers() {
  try {
    await sql`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp"`;

    // Create the "customers" table if it doesn't exist
    const createTable = await sql`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customers (
        id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
      );
    `;

    console.log(`Created "customers" table`);

    // Insert data into the "customers" table
    const insertedCustomers = await Promise.all(
      customers.map(
        (customer) => sql`
        INSERT INTO customers (id, name, email, image_url)
        VALUES (${customer.id}, ${customer.name}, ${customer.email}, ${customer.image_url})
        ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
      `
      )
    );

    console.log(`Seeded ${insertedCustomers.length} customers`);

    return {
      createTable,
      customers: insertedCustomers,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error seeding customers:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

async function seedRevenue() {
  try {
    // Create the "revenue" table if it doesn't exist
    const createTable = await sql`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS revenue (
        month VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        revenue INT NOT NULL
      );
    `;

    console.log(`Created "revenue" table`);

    // Insert data into the "revenue" table
    const insertedRevenue = await Promise.all(
      revenue.map(
        (rev) => sql`
        INSERT INTO revenue (month, revenue)
        VALUES (${rev.month}, ${rev.revenue})
        ON CONFLICT (month) DO NOTHING;
      `
      )
    );

    console.log(`Seeded ${insertedRevenue.length} revenue`);

    return {
      createTable,
      revenue: insertedRevenue,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error seeding revenue:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

(async () => {
  await seedUsers();
  await seedCustomers();
  await seedInvoices();
  await seedRevenue();
})();
```

placeholder-data.js

```
// This file contains placeholder data that you'll be replacing with real data in the Data Fetching chapter:
// https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/fetching-data
const users = [
  {
    id: '410544b2-4001-4271-9855-fec4b6a6442a',
    name: 'User',
    email: 'user@nextmail.com',
    password: '123456',
  },
];

const customers = [
  {
    id: '3958dc9e-712f-4377-85e9-fec4b6a6442a',
    name: 'Delba de Oliveira',
    email: 'delba@oliveira.com',
    image_url: '/customers/delba-de-oliveira.png',
  },
  {
    id: '3958dc9e-742f-4377-85e9-fec4b6a6442a',
    name: 'Lee Robinson',
    email: 'lee@robinson.com',
    image_url: '/customers/lee-robinson.png',
  },
  {
    id: '3958dc9e-737f-4377-85e9-fec4b6a6442a',
    name: 'Hector Simpson',
    email: 'hector@simpson.com',
    image_url: '/customers/hector-simpson.png',
  },
  {
    id: '50ca3e18-62cd-11ee-8c99-0242ac120002',
    name: 'Steven Tey',
    email: 'steven@tey.com',
    image_url: '/customers/steven-tey.png',
  },
  {
    id: '3958dc9e-787f-4377-85e9-fec4b6a6442a',
    name: 'Steph Dietz',
    email: 'steph@dietz.com',
    image_url: '/customers/steph-dietz.png',
  },
  {
    id: '76d65c26-f784-44a2-ac19-586678f7c2f2',
    name: 'Michael Novotny',
    email: 'michael@novotny.com',
    image_url: '/customers/michael-novotny.png',
  },
  {
    id: 'd6e15727-9fe1-4961-8c5b-ea44a9bd81aa',
    name: 'Evil Rabbit',
    email: 'evil@rabbit.com',
    image_url: '/customers/evil-rabbit.png',
  },
  {
    id: '126eed9c-c90c-4ef6-a4a8-fcf7408d3c66',
    name: 'Emil Kowalski',
    email: 'emil@kowalski.com',
    image_url: '/customers/emil-kowalski.png',
  },
  {
    id: 'CC27C14A-0ACF-4F4A-A6C9-D45682C144B9',
    name: 'Amy Burns',
    email: 'amy@burns.com',
    image_url: '/customers/amy-burns.png',
  },
  {
    id: '13D07535-C59E-4157-A011-F8D2EF4E0CBB',
    name: 'Balazs Orban',
    email: 'balazs@orban.com',
    image_url: '/customers/balazs-orban.png',
  },
];

const invoices = [
  {
    customer_id: customers[0].id,
    amount: 15795,
    status: 'pending',
    date: '2022-12-06',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[1].id,
    amount: 20348,
    status: 'pending',
    date: '2022-11-14',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[4].id,
    amount: 3040,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2022-10-29',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[3].id,
    amount: 44800,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-09-10',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[5].id,
    amount: 34577,
    status: 'pending',
    date: '2023-08-05',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[7].id,
    amount: 54246,
    status: 'pending',
    date: '2023-07-16',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[6].id,
    amount: 666,
    status: 'pending',
    date: '2023-06-27',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[3].id,
    amount: 32545,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-06-09',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[4].id,
    amount: 1250,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-06-17',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[5].id,
    amount: 8546,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-06-07',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[1].id,
    amount: 500,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-08-19',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[5].id,
    amount: 8945,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-06-03',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[2].id,
    amount: 8945,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-06-18',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[0].id,
    amount: 8945,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2023-10-04',
  },
  {
    customer_id: customers[2].id,
    amount: 1000,
    status: 'paid',
    date: '2022-06-05',
  },
];

const revenue = [
  { month: 'Jan', revenue: 2000 },
  { month: 'Feb', revenue: 1800 },
  { month: 'Mar', revenue: 2200 },
  { month: 'Apr', revenue: 2500 },
  { month: 'May', revenue: 2300 },
  { month: 'Jun', revenue: 3200 },
  { month: 'Jul', revenue: 3500 },
  { month: 'Aug', revenue: 3700 },
  { month: 'Sep', revenue: 2500 },
  { month: 'Oct', revenue: 2800 },
  { month: 'Nov', revenue: 3000 },
  { month: 'Dec', revenue: 4800 },
];

module.exports = {
  users,
  customers,
  invoices,
  revenue,
};
```

I have already tried this with and without `?pgbouncer=true` on the connection string.
I ran this on Node v18.18.2 and v20.9.0.
I have also destroyed the database and created a new one as well as using `DEALLOCATE ALL`.

All of these attempts did not change the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed seed.js I found on Github, with this it works:

https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/blob/271f7db0da7ecba44e06b60b22d0fde802cf19c0/dashboard/final-example/scripts/seed.js

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent the whole evening yesterday searching for a solution and was not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with copying the secrets snippet from Vercel. If you have problems with the script it is good idea to double check your .env and postgres secrets in Vercel.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting:

1. Make sure to reveal your database secrets before copying it into your .env file.

I verified that copy hidden secret values paste POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD empty "" in my local .env

2. If you run into any issues while seeding your database and want to
   run the script again, you can drop any existing tables by running DROP TABLE tablename in your database query interface. See the executing queries section below for more details. But be careful, this command will delete the tables and all their data. It's ok to do this with your example app since you're working with placeholder data, but you shouldn't run this command in a production app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just copied `.env` information by mouse, but when I pasted it into my editor, the same information was mistaken and empty. But, when I clicked the "Copy Snippet" button instead (refer to the screenshot), it copied the right information!

[image: Screenshot]